# Connecting analogue mixer console to FL studio

Tags: mixer, hardware, audio-interfaces, fl-studio, console

[image]I am to help edit audio in a live performance in which 10 microphones will be used but my audio interface only supports 2 microphones. I have an analogue mixer console that supports more than 10 microphones, but it has limited equalizers and other effects. How will i connect this mixer console to a DAW, specifically FL studio, so I would be able to use more effects, for this live performance?

Comment: I've attempted an [answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/47976/27627) in the [question you posted](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/47970/27627)  in the [Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer really made me understand a lot of @joseem

Comment: if this question is answered, why don't you mark it as answered